Svelte LayoutServerLoad fetch Wrong Routing in Kubernetes
I have a +layout.server.ts in my SvelteKit application which should load some data from an api endpoint. It looks similar to this:
import { env } from '$env/dynamic/public';

export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async ({ fetch }) => {
    const apiUrl = `${env.PUBLIC_API_URI}/some/subpath`;
    console.log('Fetching data', { apiUrl });
    const res = await fetch(apiUrl);
    Log.debug('Fetched flow', {
        apiUrl,
        status: res.status
    });

    if (!res.ok) {
        error(500, 'failed to fetch data');
    }

    // Some more logic and a return
};

In my local dev environment everything works fine. Things get wired if I deploy this application to my Kubernetes Cluster.
In my deployment the PUBLIC_API_URI is set to something like https://example.com/api. I also have an Ingress configured which routes the traffic to different services.
https://example.com/**/*     --> goes to the svelte application
https://example.com/api/**/* --> goes to my api service

The fetch request inside the LayoutServerLoad gets routed to my svelte application. I expect that the fetch request is handled by the api service.
The wired thing is that when I open the url which gets logged by the line console.log('Fetching data', { apiUrl }); in my browser the request is handled by the api service as expected. So I guess my ingress configuration is not the problem.
Has anyone an idea why the fetch call is not handled by the api service?

Is the problem Internal requests (e.g. for +server.js routes) go directly to the handler function when running on the server, without the overhead of an HTTP call?

Good hint! I actually seems like there is no HTTP request anywhere in the logs. Is there any option to disable this feature for the specific request? I did not found anything about that in the docs. I could use the "standard" fetch call but unfortunately i need to inherits the cookies from the page request....

Maybe it's as easy as removing fetch in the function parameter list, but don't know ^^'

@PeppeL-G It actually solved the problem. Thanks!
As mentioned I need to forward a cookie (csrf_token) from the client to the server as well. The svelte fetch implementation handles this automatically. With the default fetch I need to set the cookies manual like this: fetch('someUrl', {headers: {Cookie: "myCookie=" +cookies.get('mycookie')}}). But I guess thats the only option right know.
Thanks again for the hint. I struggled hours to debug this :D
